# Fiber to copper switching - small network requiring robust solution

Tags: switch, vlan, local-area-network

I have a simple setup which appears to require a clever solution; hoping someone has some ideas.

Network:

- 4 data generating computers, each with a copper->fiber media converter
- 2 data analyzing computers
- SM fiber runs from all four data generating computers to the room containing the data analyzing computers
- 1Gb Cat-5 NICS in all computers

I have a team of people who do data analysis on the analyzing computers.  At any given time they need to specify which (singular) data generating computer they need to receive data from (TCP socket connections).  Thus, there needs to be a simple way for them to select, either on a physical device or using a custom, read fool-proof, UI which data generating computer is connected to that particular data analyzing computer.

My predecessor's solution is to use two media converters and have the operators plug in the correct fiber pair.  This is abhorrent for obvious reasons.

Apparently, the solution before that was to use a manual fiber switch of some sort but it was too unreliable given SM tolerances.

One idea is to just get an unmanaged switch with sufficient SFP and Copper ports and hope that both data analysis computers don't try to connect to the same data generating computer.

Maybe more robust would be to get a managed switch and write the UI such that the software could modify the port isolation settings or port settings on four VLANs (one for each data generating computer).

Any votes or other ideas?

I will also note that the current setup has all of the data generating computers using the same IP address and all of the data analyzing computers using the same IP address -- which works because the operator is just setting up a P2P network by switching the fibers in the media converters.  I'm already hearing belly-aching from the data analysis software developer about having to track different IP addresses in my new switch scheme, but I don't see how it can be avoided?

Comment: Using the same IP address for all the computers is, as you might say, abhorrent.  If you can't change that, your current solution is as good (bad) as any.

Comment: I agree.  I'm not saying it can't be changed.

Comment: So, if all computers have a unique IP address, will the users be able to select a generating computer by IP/Name?

Comment: Sure.  I think the soreness comes from the fact that the existing software automatically makes the TCP connections to the known (non-unique) IP address on startup.  Changing to unique addresses requires moving that code to after some GUI selection of Name/IP.  Like I said, it's belly-aching, but as I'm the one waltzing in the door demanding a solution I'm trying to create a case better than, "it's bad/risky to regularly plug/unplug fiber."

Comment: Do you actually *require* fiber for reach, EMI immunity or such? Otherwise, get rid of the converters, get a decent switch, renumber the network and that's it. If fiber is required, use a managed switch as converter. If all else fails, use VLANs to make the logic connections.

Comment: The fiber is already in place and is required for EMI considerations and length of run.  I think we'll go with the managed switch notion and enforce the p2p connections with VLANS or port isolation or perhaps just with software.  I appreciate the opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the KISS principle, add a third box and have the 2 data generating servers send their data to it, and use ELK (or similar) to parse it from the other 2 or any other PC on your network. Give them all different IP's and make this a standard network stack setup.